# deleting parent exception with jpa

Tags: jpa, mapping, entity, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

With netbeans 8.1 I have generated entity and jpa controller.
I have a parent entity and a child with a one to one relation.
The child entity has primary key equals to foreign key to the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@XmlRootElement
public class Parent implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Integer id;
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
 private Child child;

 public Parent() {
 }
    etc....
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@XmlRootElement
public class Child implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "parent_id")
  private Integer parentId;
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  private Parent parent;
  public Child() {
  }
  etc....
 }
```

When I try to delete the parent I get:

```
IllegalOrphanException: This Parent (model.Parent[ id=1 ]) cannot be destroyed since the Child model.Child[ parentId=1 ] in its child field has a non-nullable parent field.
```

To avoid this I should delete the child first, but due to cascade.ALL it should be already done automatically.

Comment: It is a bidirectional relationship, controlled by the child side so the first question would be - was the reference set?  JPA can only cascade across the reference if you have been maintaining it.  Try calling em.refresh on your parent reference before deleting it, and if that works, make sure you set the parent.child reference when creating the child instance.

Comment: Setting parent.child reference when I create I get "EntityNotFoundException: Could not find Entity for id: 1".

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to find the child entity before persisting it? You have the parent instance presumably, and are creating the child so there should be no need to look it up. when you set child.parent= parent, also set parent.child=child.

Answer (score 0):

Coding Child class as follows works

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@XmlRootElement
public class Child implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  private Parent parent;
  ...
}
```

Tables look like

```
create table child (parent_id integer not null,..., primary key (parent_id))
create table parent (id integer not null, ..., primary key (id))
alter table child add constraint ... foreign key (parent_id) references parent
```

The removal of a parent (`em.remove(parent)`) leads to

```
delete from child where parent_id=?
delete from parent where id=?
```